# C++17 check for valid expression

Tags: c++, c++17

Basing my code on [this](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/checking_expression_validity_in_place.html) and [this](https://github.com/SuperV1234/vittorioromeo.info/blob/master/extra/in_place_expr_validity/2_cpp17.cpp), I've written this version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <boost/callable_traits/is_invocable.hpp>

#define IS_VALID_EXPANDER_BEGIN(count)                    \
    [](BOOST_PP_REPEAT(count, IS_VALID_EXPANDER_MIDDLE, \
        _)) constexpr->decltype IS_VALID_EXPANDER_END

#define IS_VALID_EXPANDER_MIDDLE(z, idx, _) BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(idx) auto _##idx

#define IS_VALID_EXPANDER_END(...) \
    (__VA_ARGS__){})

#define IS_VALID(...)                              \
    is_valid<__VA_ARGS__>(IS_VALID_EXPANDER_BEGIN( \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__))

template <typename... Ts, typename TF>
static constexpr auto is_valid(TF)
{
    return boost::callable_traits::is_invocable<std::decay_t<TF>(Ts...), Ts...>{};
}

struct Test {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << IS_VALID(std::ostream&, double)(_0 << _1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << IS_VALID(std::ostream&, Test)(_0 << _1) << std::endl;
}
```

However, the results are:

```
1
1
```

I can't figure out why.

Comment: C++17 and you're messing with variadic macros why?

Comment: @rubenvb: author of the linked articles here. The variadic macros are just a way of providing syntactic sugar for in-place expression validity evaluation. Without macros the caller side would look hideous, harming readability and defeating the purpose of this construct.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice this code came from somewhere describing its use. Never mond my comment then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambda is taking arguments by value, which doesn't allow you to test `std::ostream& << T`. Change your macro to:

```
#define IS_VALID_EXPANDER_BEGIN(count)                    \
    [](BOOST_PP_REPEAT(count, IS_VALID_EXPANDER_MIDDLE, \
        &&_)) constexpr->decltype IS_VALID_EXPANDER_END
```

Also, your use of `is_invocable` is wrong - it should be:

```
template <typename... Ts, typename TF>
static constexpr auto is_valid(TF)
{
    return boost::callable_traits::is_invocable<std::decay_t<TF>, Ts...>{};
}
```

(You should use `std::is_invocable` anyway, it is available in C++17.)

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mQLEo5siW7FYnbkw)

Comment: The code works. For some reason my library does not have 'std::is_invocable'. Shouldn't your code have the && as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

template<class F>
constexpr auto invokeable( F&& f ) {
  return [](auto&&...args) {
    return std::is_invocable< F&&, decltype(args)... >{};
  };
}
```

now we can do with far less macro magic:

```
std::cout << invokeable([](auto& lhs, auto&& v) RETURNS( lhs << v ))( std::cout, 0.0 ) << std::endl;
std::cout << invokeable([](auto& lhs, auto&& v) RETURNS( lhs << v ))( std::cout, Test{} ) << std::endl;
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c8a4b1a9282f280).

If `_0 << _1` builds a SFINAE friendly callable object (as it appears to), you could even do:

```
std::cout << invokeable(_0 << _1)( std::cout, Test{} ) << std::endl;
```

`invokeable` is a function object adapter.  It turns a function object into a tester to see if arguments passed to it are legal.

It does require you to actually have the arguments of the right type.  You can get around this as follows:

```
template<class T>
struct tag_t { using type=T; };
template<class T>
constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};

template<class X>
struct untag { using type=X; };
template<class X>
using untag_t = typename untag<X>::type;
template<class T>
struct untag<tag_t<T>> { using type=T; };
template<class T>
struct untag<tag_t<T>&&> { using type=T; };
template<class T>
struct untag<tag_t<T>&> { using type=T; };
template<class T>
struct untag<tag_t<T>const &> { using type=T; };
```

then modify:

```
template<class F>
constexpr auto invokeable( F&& f ) {
  return [](auto&&...args) {
    return std::is_invocable< F&&, untag_t<decltype(args)>... >{};
  };
}
```

which permits passing `tag<std::ostream&>` instead of an lvalue of type `std::ostream&` to test if all `std::ostream&` would work in that slot.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac242d403a4d9bd4).

The only macro used here is `RETURNS`, which makes making SFINAE-friendly lambdas easier.  And there are a number of proposals to add something equivalent to `RETURNS` in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) in any case.

Comment: *"there are a number of proposals to add something equivalent to `RETURNS`"* - the only thing I remember seeing was Barry's rejected terse lambda syntax proposal. What else is there?

Comment: @vitt I think I sae another one go by, but it might have been coroutines